# What is the difference between Web Service VS a Service that runs on Server?

Tags: web-services, service, tcp, serversocket

I have used ASP.NET Web Services (.asmx) in the past. However, I have heard references to having a "Service" running on a server that you can use.

Mainly, I am curious what this "Service" is.

Is it a Windows Application actually running on the server that you can connect to?

Can I create a "Service" on a server that I could create a direct TCP/IP connection to from a client windows 7 computer? Would this connection be bi-directional? Could this connection be pooled/persistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Service was the buzzword used before the "Cloud" was spawned, most people had no idea what they were talking about..

There are a myriad of different "Services" out there.. when you say ASP.NET Web Services, I'm assuming you mean .asmx service files? (a negligible detail IMO)

to your question:

yes, you can create a "Service" on your Web Server that can be accessed by various clients over the inter / intra - net. You can even create an entire "class library" which is only accessible by different "Service" calls from these various clients.. there are lots of benefits to using a "Service" style architecture in one form or another, however, google has loads more info on that..

and to your TCP / IP question.. yes. Web Services provide different kinds transport / bindings including TCP, HTTP, etc..

for more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163394.aspx

Comment: To clarify, when you say "you can create a 'Service' on you Web Server" you are referring to a Windows Application running on the Web Server?

Comment: No, it's a web service, which would be web application i guess.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Windows service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service) on wikipedia may give you some hints...

Comment: Is a Windows service what people are referring to when they say a "Service" running on the server?

Comment: They could be referring to [tag:wcf].

Comment: I guess it depends on context (i.e. whom you talk to). Having worked on both, when someone mentions simple "service" I associate it with the windows service. As for the second part of your question (create service on a web server), definitely. You can have a look to [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) which some use to create web services/APIs for their existent sites.

Comment: I have created SOAP services before. With a REST service, could my web-server initiate the connection to a stored client and push data?

Comment: @Mausimo I don't think so. You have to implement the [push protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) somehow.

Comment: @Equinoxel - I am looking for a push protocol that does not leverage a web browser. Preferably I would make a connection to a client application written in C.